# Bootstrap toast - Data delay not respected - Toast dont hide

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, toast

After hit the submit button of a form (Ajax POST) I want to refresh the toast with the message generated in Django view. I succeed to show the message but the data-delay is not respected, the toast does not disappear after 5 sec.

```
<div id="messages" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: relative">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 12px; right: 12px;" >
            {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="toast d-flex toast-success" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-delay="3000">
                        <div class="toast-header toast-success shadow-none" >
                            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="toast-body">
                            {{message}} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in success part of Ajax, I have the following code:

```
$('#messages).load(location.href + " #messages>*", "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` in this case:

```
$("#messages").load(location.href + " #messages>*", "");
setTimeout(function(){$("#messages").empty();}, 5000);
```

---

**Update**

Prevent the function set with the setTimeout() to execute:

```
var myTimeout;

function myFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  $("#messages").load(location.href + " #messages>*", "");
  myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){$("#messages").empty();}, 5000);
}
```

Comment: let say I hit the submit, the message appears => OK

Comment: If I hit again the submit button 4 sec after, the second message disappear with the first timeout

Comment: @MichaelS, you can use ` clearTimeout() `. See update

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!